# akka-http custom PathMatcher

Tags: scala, akka-http

Many of directives (e.g., [parameters](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.5/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#parameters-scala)) gives very convenient unmarshalling mechanism.

But I failed to find similar DSL for the [Path Matcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.5/scala/http/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html#the-pathmatcher-dsl) from the documentation. 
I thought that given proper Unmarshaller, I would something like below,

```
implicit val userStatusUnmarshaller: FromStringUnmarshaller[UserStatus] = ???
val route = path("user" / Segment.as[UserStatus]) { status: UserStatus => 
    ...
}
```

expecially when the custom unmarshalling result is Enumeration.

Do they give such a way but I couldn't find or is there another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about implicitly extend `PathMatcher1[String]` asking for something `String => Option[T]`.

```scala
implicit class PimpedSegment(segment: PathMatcher1[String]) {
  def as[T](implicit asT: String => Option[T]): PathMatcher1[T] =
    segment.flatMap(asT)
}
```

For example you could implicitly require a `JsonReader[T]`:

```scala
implicit class JsonSegment(segment: PathMatcher1[String]) {
  def as[T: JsonReader]: PathMatcher1[T] = segment.flatMap { string =>
    Try(JsString(string).convertTo[T]).toOption
  }
}
```

Then it can be used as `Segment.as[UserStatus]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can flatMap segment to UserStatus like so:

```
    Segment.flatMap(UserStatus.fromString)
```

`fromString` should return `Option[UserStatus]`